# Error during external image load

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

My app usually works fine but sometimes (once in year) Image does not load and gives error like below:

> flqnx[262196-1]: debug: trace: [object File] flqnx[262196-1]: debug:
>   trace: app:/META-INF/AIR flqnx[262196-1]: debug: trace: Extensions to
>   load: 0

I cannot use *upgraded AIR version* as a possible solution.

This is my problem code :

```
   function LoadImage() {
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onContentLoadInfo, false, 0, true);
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onContentLoadError, false, 0, true);
     loader.load(new URLRequest(sourcePath));
 }


 function onContentLoadInfo(e: Event) {
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onContentLoadInfo);
     loader.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onContentLoadError);
     if (e.target.hasOwnProperty("content")) {
         this.bitmapData = e.target.content.bitmapData.clone();
         this.smoothing = true;
         this.dispatchEvent(new Event(EVENT_IMAGE_LOADED, false, false));
     }
 }
```

Comment: It works fine always.But sometime(once in year) Image does not load and gives error lie below:

flqnx[262196-1]: debug: trace: [object File]
flqnx[262196-1]: debug: trace: app:/META-INF/AIR
flqnx[262196-1]: debug: trace: Extensions to load: 0

I can not upgrade AIR version now. Can you please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: Use a separate method to handle error cases (IOError or SecurityError), which retries to load the image. If, as you state, the error is not persistent, it will solve the problem.